# how to implement layer wise scrollview in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

is following  possible using  ccscrolllayer

```
CCScrollLayer *scroller = [[CCScrollLayer alloc] initWithLayers:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: pageoneScroll,pageTwoScroll,pageThreeScroll,pageFourScroll,pageFiveScroll,pageSixScroll,pageSeventhScroll,pageEightScroll,pageNinethScroll,pageTenthScroll,pageEleventhScroll,pageTventhScroll,pageThirteenthScroll,pageFourteenthScroll,nil] widthOffset: 0];

// finally add the scroller to your scene
[self addChild:scroller];
```

Comment: i tried above code working fine but it is back to back scrolling not layer wise scrolling thanks in advance!

Comment: please mention your question in brief